# It’s September again

Tags: discussion

[Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) doesn’t end, but does wax and wane with the school season. [It’s waxing again](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/510565).

Be prepared to spot and quickly VtC unvarnished orders to do others’ homework.

Also please downvote, so that unacceptable questions don’t sit on the front page, creating an open invitation for yet more.

For the quality ones which show effort, an eagerness to engage, and a clear and well-posed question, consider either pointing OP to ELL in a comment, or for the best examples, vote to migrate.

Be civil, polite, and firm. [Do not feed the bears](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1236/10446).

Comment: You forgot to invite seasoned user to be more active on the Qs side. We shouldn’t just  rely on new users for getting engaging posts. :)

Comment: @user067531 I agree we must encourage more valuable Qs. I don’t think we will get them from the regulars around here, for a variety of reasons which have been discussed from time to time here on Meta. I think we do need to get them from new users, but we should source those new users from likely places: other centers of English study and enthusiasm on the web. I posted here about this once, I think.

Comment: Wake Me Up When September Ends 

Comment: It's not just students...lately I am seeing a spate of questions from "English teachers" who do not know how to explain their own course material.

Comment: I think it was the First Lord of the Treasury who [wrote](https://news.sky.com/story/boris-johnson-branded-david-cameron-girly-swot-leaked-document-reveals-11803807): *"The whole September session is a rigmarole introduced by girly swot Cameron and show the public that MPs are earning their crust."* Let us take heed of those words, enjoy this September and earn your crusts!